# How can I retrieve the package-relevant architecture of a Debian Linux system?

Tags: arm, cpu-architecture, apt, dpkg, debian-based

I currently try to build a Debian package for the [armhf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture_family#Floating-point_(VFP)) (ARMv7) architecture, but I want the build script to recognize the architecture itself. The problem is, that I can not find the architecture, that [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software)) uses to retrieve the package from a repository.

In my case, APT uses `armhf`, when it retrieves *packages*.

When I run `uname -m`, I get `armv7` as a result. A `grep -rn armhf /etc` does not show any appearance of `armhf`, relevant for APT to choose from.

So, where can I get ([Debian 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_9_(Stretch)) (Stretch) or [Armbian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armbian) next) a reliable source for that information from the system that is independent of the architecture (my script should run also on i686, amd64, armel & arm64)?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
dpkg --print-architecture
```

This gives you the architecture Debian is selecting for packages. I'm not sure what happens on multi-architecture systems (i686 and amd64), but this can be separated quite easily.